# protocol assosiatedtype and generic class initialization

Tags: swift, generics, dependency-injection, protocols, swift5

I have class `PaginatorImp` which implements protocol `Paginator` for dependency injection. In factory i want to create `PaginatorImp` throw protocol but i cant because protocol with associatedtype. How can i solve it?

`Paginator` class (`Element` is a model that conforms to `Paginatable`)

```
protocol Paginator {
    associatedtype Element: Paginatable

    var isLoading: Bool { get }

    //MARK: Actions
    var loadAction: Action<Void, Element>! { get set }
    var refreshAction: Action<Void, Element>! { get set }
    var loadMoreAction: Action<Int, Element>! { get set }
    var loadItemsIfNeeded: PublishRelay<Void> { get }

    //MARK: Data
    var elements: BehaviorRelay<([Element.Content], IndexSet?)> { get }
}

final class PaginatorImp<Element: Paginatable>: Paginator {
    private let disposeBag: DisposeBag = .init()

    //MARK: properties
    private var page: Int = 1
    private var pagesCount: Int = 1
    var isLoading: Bool = false

    //MARK: Data
    var elements: BehaviorRelay<([Element.Content], IndexSet?)> = .init(value: ([], nil))
```

Factory (i use EasyDI for DI)

> Error: Protocol 'Paginator' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

```
final class ServicesFactory: Assembly {
    var paginator: Paginator { return define(init: PaginatorImp<News>())}
}
```

Comment: You might need a type eraser here

Comment: @Cristik thank you, it helps me